# Checking function calling inside POST request handler

Tags: node.js, rest, sinon, supertest

I need to test that my `POST /login` handler calling `validServiceURL` function inside itself.

I tried to solve this issue using `spy` from `sinon`, but didn't manage it.

`POST /login` handler:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (await validServiceURL(req.headers.host)) {
            await checkUser(req, res);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        reditectToHomePageWithError(res, err.message);
    }
};
```

Test code:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const request = require("supertest");

chai.use(require("sinon-chai"));
const expect = chai.expect;

const app = require("../../app");
const validServiceURL = require("../../lib/validServiceURL");

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe("User", function() {
    describe("POST login", function() {
        it("should call validServiceURL with provided serviceURL", async () => {
            let args = { username: user.username, password: password };
            let serviceURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3030";

            let spyValidServiceURL = sandbox.spy(validServiceURL);

            await request(app)
                .post("/login")
                .type("form")
                .send(args)
                .set("host", serviceURL);

            expect(spyValidServiceURL).to.have.been.calledWith(serviceURL);

            sandbox.restore();
        });
    });
});
```

When I run this test I get error look like:

> AssertionError: expected validServiceURL to have been called with arguments http://127.0.0.1:3030

Answer (score 0):

`sinon` doesn't support stub/spy a standalone function directly. In your case, the standalone function is `validServiceURL`. For more info, see this [issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562).

Here is the solution using `proxyquire` module:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const validServiceURL = require("./validServiceURL");
const app = express();

async function checkUser(req, res) {
  console.log("checkUser");
}

function reditectToHomePageWithError(res, message) {
  console.log(message);
}

const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (await validServiceURL(req.headers.host)) {
      await checkUser(req, res);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    reditectToHomePageWithError(res, err.message);
  }
};

app.post("/login", login);

module.exports = app;
```

`validServiceURL.js`:

```js
async function validServiceURL() {}

module.exports = validServiceURL;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const request = require("supertest");
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");

chai.use(require("sinon-chai"));
const expect = chai.expect;

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe("User", function() {
  describe("POST login", function() {
    it("should call validServiceURL with provided serviceURL", async () => {
      let args = { username: "username", password: "password" };
      let serviceURL = "http://127.0.0.1:3030";

      let spyValidServiceURL = sandbox.spy();
      const app = proxyquire("./app", {
        "./validServiceURL": spyValidServiceURL,
      });

      await request(app)
        .post("/login")
        .type("form")
        .send(args)
        .set("host", serviceURL);

      expect(spyValidServiceURL).to.have.been.calledWith(serviceURL);

      sandbox.restore();
    });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage:

```sh
  User
    POST login
      ✓ should call validServiceURL with provided serviceURL (468ms)


  1 passing (474ms)

--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files           |     87.1 |       50 |    57.14 |     87.1 |                   |
 app.js             |    69.23 |       50 |    33.33 |    69.23 |        6,10,16,21 |
 app.test.js        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 validServiceURL.js |      100 |      100 |        0 |      100 |                   |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57908094